# WSO2 JSON to SOAP converstion

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-appm, wso2-esb

JSON to XML converstion using WSO2 API Manager Sequence

I need to convert JSON request to SOAP and SOAP response to JSON.
I can do it for the JSON objects but I am unable to do it for the json array object.

For the below soap format and arguments. JSON array can contain multiple elements but here I have provided only one 
 
For Ex: key and values are json array object.
here soapKey will hold json key and soapValue holds json value of the first element of the JSON array.

```
<format>
<ns:soapField>$1</ns:soapField> 
<ns:soapValue>$2</ns:soapValue>
</format>

<args>
<arg evaluator="xml" expression="//request/jsonKey"/>
<arg evaluator="xml" expression="//request/jsonValue"/>
</args>
```

can you please suggest how to resolve this issue.